# How do I prevent ReSharper from prefixing built in types with an '@' symbol when generating code?

Tags: c#, resharper-9.0, resharper-plugins, resharper-sdk

I am writing a ReSharper plugin and I want to do this:

```
CSharpElementFactory factory = CSharpElementFactory.GetInstance(treeNode.GetPsiModule());
factory.CreateTypeMemberDeclaration(
    "public static $0 $1 (this $2 $4) { }",
    "string",
    someMethodName, 
    someArgumentType,
    SomeArgumentName);
```

which I want to output the code:

```
public static string SomeMethodName(this SomeArgumentType someArgumentName) { }
```

but it actually outputs this:

```
public static @string SomeMethodName(this SomeArgumentType someArgumentName) { }
```

it seems to do this with `int` (and I assume other built in types or keywords).

How can I prevent it from doing this and outputting valid code?

Answer (score 1):

if you'd like to use keyword 'string' you can't use quotations for it. Use 'string' in the pattern (otherwise ReSharper will try to escape 'string' keyword to use in the identifier position):

```
public static string $0 (this $1 $2){}
```

If you'd like to use 'System.String' you can explicitly bind '$0' to IDeclaredType for string:

```
IPsiModule module;
  factory.CreateTypeMemberDeclaration("public static $0 $1 (this $2 $4){}",module.GetPredefinedType().String,someMethodName, someArgumentType,SomeArgumentName);
```

ReSharper should follow code style in this case and automatically replace it with 'string' when code style is set to use keywords, but I'm not sure that it will work =(

Comment: Thanks. I am not hardcoding the 'string', instead I'm getting from an `IPredefinedTypeUsage` from navigating the code tree. Basically I have a plugin which I want to create an extension method if a method is undefined on an instance, and I want to workout the return type that the method should take based on the usage in the code, and at this point I don't have an `IDeclaredType` I don't think.